# man, how to open another topic?

Tags: man

I thought I could click or press some hot key to jump to another topic on a `man` page, but searching Google says that they are not hyperlinks. Then, other than existing the current man page and typing `man <another topic>`, is there a faster way to jump to another topic? Something like open an input box and typing the topic name?

Example: Open `git-init` whilst reading this page

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text-based `man` implementations generally use an external pager such as `less` to view man pages, and there is no support for links there.

There are other man page browsers which provide links and the ability to change page without exiting. [pinfo](https://github.com/baszoetekouw/pinfo) for example is a text-mode man page and info browser. It will convert text formatted like a man page name (“foo(1)”) into links. Pressing <kbd>g</kbd> within the program allows you to enter a man page name to change pages without a link.